# How can a combobox store different type field values in MS Access database or have a dynamic column type

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, combobox

My goal is that the user chooses the type of field search and according to that another combo box show that available field:

[image]

`CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Phone` are the columns of the `Customer` table.

If I choose customer ID in first the adjacent box shows:

[image]

When I choose first name as an option:

[image]

But after pressing Enter on "Dog", I get an error

> The value you entered isn't valid for this field

The code for the combo box 2 is:

```
Private Sub SelctionBY_AfterUpdate()
Dim iVal
iVal = Me.SelctionBY.Value
Dim S As String
S = "SELECT  " & iVal & ", CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, Phone From Customer"
Me.Combo33.RowSource = S
End Sub
```

So how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A combobox doesn't store anything, it's just for selection of something!

Data is stored in table fields and a combobox can be bound to a field to store data.

Your issue is that the bound field type changes, but it shouldn't. You can avoid that by binding the data field to the second column of the combobox, as`CustomerID`is customer tables PK(Primary Key) that should be stored as FK(Foreign Key)

```vb
Me.Combo33.BoundColumn = 2
```